# Замена буквы на заглавную

Tags: javascript

Выдает "arr.replace is not a function"

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var arr = str.split(" ");

  var firstLetter = arr[2][0].toUpperCase();
  var newStr = arr.replace(arr[2][0], firstLetter);
  return newStr;
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: ваш `arr` массив, а  `replace` функция строки

Comment: но ведь. если я правильно понимаю, arr[2][0] - это строка

Comment: вы реплейс к чему применить пытаетесь ?

Comment: к первой букве третьего по счету элемента массива

Comment: вы применяете реплейс к переменной `arr`, внимательно посмотрите что из себя являет эта переменная

Comment: спасибо, понял!